# How to update an array using redux reducer, I want to change a boolean property inside an array of objects to make i true or false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an array, every time I fire an action it adds a new item in the array with the value true and or false, I need to change that code to return the real number of the array not adding new items

Here is my code,

```
import {ads} from '../../data/ads';
import {ADD_TO_FAVORITE} from '../types';

interface ActionInter {
  type: string;
  payload: {id: number};
}

const initialState = {
  allAds: ads,
  myFavorite: [],
};

const myFavorite = (state = initialState, action: ActionInter) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_FAVORITE:
      const itemFav = state.allAds[action.payload.id - 1].isFav;
      console.log(itemFav);

      if (itemFav === true)
        return {
          ...state,
          allAds: [
            ...state.allAds,
            (state.allAds[action.payload.id - 1].isFav = false),
          ],
        };

      if (itemFav === false)
        return {
          ...state,
          allAds: [
            ...state.allAds,
            (state.allAds[action.payload.id - 1].isFav = true),
          ],
        };
  }
  return state;
};

export default myFavorite;
```

ads, it's an array of objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can using `map` like this:

```
const myFavorite = (state = initialState, action: ActionInter) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_FAVORITE:
      return {
        ...state,
        allAds: state.allAds.map((item, index) => {
          return action.payload.id - 1 === index
            ? {
                ...item,
                isFav: !item.isFav,
              }
            : item;
        }),
      };
  }
  return state;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
const myFavorite = (state = initialState, action: ActionInter) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_TO_FAVORITE:
            const index = action.payload.id - 1;
            const newAllAds = [...state.allAds];
            newAllAds[index].isFav = !newAllAds[index].isFav;
            return {
                ...state,
                allAds: newAllAds,
            };
    }
    return state;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use immutability, **instead of updating the previous state, create a copy and update that copy**

```
const myFavorite = (state = initialState, action: ActionInter) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_FAVORITE: {
      // Using the spread operator we'll create a copy
      const allAdsCopy = [...state.allAds];

      // Identify the item index
      const index = action.payload.id -1;

      // Update the copy
      allAdsCopy[index].isFav = !allAdsCopy[index].isFav;

      return {
        ...state,
        allAds : allAdsCopy,
      };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```